# IOS Jailbreak: Make device sleep/standby from CLI

Tags: ios, jailbreak, command-line-interface

Does anyone know if there is any CLI command that will put my device to sleep and lock it?... just as if someone would push the powerbutton? I found a halt command but this turn the device completely off.. all I want to do is put it to sleep and lock it..

Comment: Do you know how to program for iOS?  If so, we might be able to find a *programmatic* way for you to write your own non-graphical application to do this.  If you're simply looking for a command to install, then that's not a question for Stack Overflow (which is a programming site).